# Error in storing xml into an object in powersell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an xml that looks like this:

```
<AccountRequest application="Active Directory" op="Create" nativeIdentity="CN=estest,OU=Users,OU=Test User Provisioning,DC=testtcbna,DC=net">
    <AttributeRequest op="Set">
    <Attributes>
      <Map>
        <entry key="Employee id" value="109844" />
        <entry key="Manager" value="Testerman,Maria" />
        <entry key="Location" value="Austin - San Jacinto: Floor 2" />
        <entry key="isManager" value="No" />
        <entry key="Department" value="Information Security" />
        <entry key="Associate id" value="30009" />
        <entry key="Effective Date" value="12/15/2021" />
        <entry key="Name" value="Testerman, Esteban" />
      </Map>
    </Attributes>
    </AttributeRequest>
    </AttributeRequest>
</AccountRequest>
```

My end goal is to parse the xml so I can store values of attributes inside the map "employee" , "manager" and such in a variable. I was looking at an example that suggested I store the xml file into an object . So I tried

```
[xml]$accountRequest = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\dikark\OneDrive\Documents\accountRequest.xml
Write-Output $accountRequest.
```

But I get this error:

> Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type
> "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "The specified node cannot be
> inserted as the valid child of this node, because the  specified node
> is the wrong type." At line:12 char:1
>
>  + [xml]$accountRequest = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\dikark'OneDrive -  ...
>
>  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>       + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
>
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException Edit: last two closing tags were omitted. Adding it back.

Comment: The XML sample you've shown is definitely _not_ a valid XML document. Closing tag for the `AccountRequest` and `AttributeRequest` nodes are missing (at the very least)

Comment: Sorry, they did not appear due to no indentation. I have fixed it . xml does have the closing tags.

Comment: Looks like you have a duplicate `</attributerequest>` tag

Comment: There are several online XML validation sites, you should use them.